# escape from pdf files using vimperator

Tags: pdf, vimperator

About a year ago I switched to gvim as my main text editor. In order get the same benefits when browsing, I installed vimperator. It is not perfect, but does a good job at replicating vim functionality in the browser. The thing that bothers me most is pdf-files. When I open those, I am sometimes able to return to normal mode using escape, but often there seems to be no way except by taking the mouse to open a new tab. The whole point of using vimperator is to avoid using the mouse, so this is clearly undesired behaviour. Is there any way to "escape" the Acrobat plugin using the keyboard only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the Adobe plugin is sometimes swallowing the keypresses (probably because the PDF you're viewing has forms / etc) and they're not reaching Firefox / Vimperator.

If you would be open to using Firefox's internal PDF viewer, then I think you'll find the Vimperator key-bindings continue to work even when viewing a PDF.

You can set this in Preferences > Applications > Portable Document Format (PDF) > Preview in Firefox.

Comment: That indeed seems to work nicely. I would still prefer acrobat, but if nobody comes up with a way to make that work I'll accept this answer.